# Is there an option in ReSharper to not put an object initializer on multiple lines?

Tags: c#, resharper

Every time I type an object initializer as a parameter, like this:

```
SomeFunc(new { Id = id })
```

and type the semicolon afterwards, ReSharper formats what I just typed, as configured.
However, I cannot find an option in ReSharper to make it not turn my code into this:

```
SomeFunc(new {
  Id = id
});
```

I did confirm it actually is ReSharper doing the formatting.

Comment: I have looked several times before and have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to keep ReSharper from formatting your object initializers (so you can decide how you want to format them yourself), I think a combination of these settings will do the job.

`Keep existing line breaks` : `[Checked]`

`Place simple array, object and collection on single line` : `[Checked]`

`Wrap object and collection initializer` : `'Simple wrap'`

`Wrap long lines` : `[Unchecked]`

Of course, these settings might not fit everyone's situation, but I'm sure you can adapt them to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to set `Wrap object and collection initializer` option to `Chop if long` in `Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping` section.

Comment: I already have that setting set to "Chop if long", however, it still has this behavior for *every* line.