# visual studio or resharper auto formatting javascript array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, formatting

Whenever I type a semicolon to close a statement containing an array declaration, Visual Studio or ReSharper are applying a new line after '[' character.

So when I declare something like this

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

as soon as I type the last semicolon it get's autoformatted to this

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', [
    '$scope', function($scope){

}]);
```

But I've looked all through both Visual Studio's and ReSharper's javascript line break formatting and I see no rule that would apply to this. Help, this is very annoying behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12446192/360067